# PHP место кирилицы дает вопросительнеые знаки

Tags: php, json

Занимаюсь мобильной разработкой с PHP дел не имел. имеется скрипт который бд mysql преобразует вJSon формат,но кириллицу не может место кириллицы задает просто вопросительные знаки, очень прошу помочь:

```
    <?php   
$db_name="probnik";
$mysql_user="root";
$mysql_pass="";
$server_name="localhost";


$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);



$Name=$_POST['Query'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM exam  WHERE Name LIKE '%$Name'";

$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($query){
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
$data[]=$row;
}
print(json_encode($data));
}else{
echo('Not Found');
}
mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй добавить после подключения к бд

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
```

И сам файл php сохраняй в формате UTF-8.

Comment: в какю часть кода его добав?

Comment: Автор вопроса не использует функций `mysql_` в своем коде!

Comment: @elik Попробуй добавить сразу после подключения к бд.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_set_charset() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in E:\wamp64\www\example\init.php on line 14

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: Query in E:\wamp64\www\example\init.php on line 1

Comment: вот такое выдает

Comment: как я понел надо дать 2 параметра 1 не хватает

Comment: @elik Эх, давно с php не работал, нужно ссылку на соединение дать, в твоем случае это $con, я поправил ответ.

Comment: щас такое вдыл место кирилицы

Comment: 3c\u0442\u043c\u0442\u043c\u0438\u0442\u043c\u0438\u0442","name":"\u043c\u0442\u043c\u0442\u043c\u0438\u0442\u043c\u0438\u044

Comment: а как с этим бороться?((

Comment: я уже замучался 2 день со скриптом немогу справться

Comment: но уже чтото хоть не вопросики)

Comment: @elik а нужно заного все данные строковые ввести, теперь уже с кодировкой utf-8. Просто используй ее везде.

Comment: в базе данных ве заново ввдить?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49421/discussion-between---and-elik).